# Array of strings and pointer runs for every char in the array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers

In the `C` code

```
char a[][10]={"AIZEN","GINJO","ISHIDA","PERNIDA","GRIMMJOW"};
char (*ptr)[10]=a;
while(*ptr!='\0'){
    printf("%s\n",*ptr);
    ptr++;
}
```

Loop runs 31 times, which is equal to number of characters in the array `a`. When I change the line 3 as

```
while((*ptr)[10]!='\0'){
```

Loop runs 5 times, printing the names in the array. Why 
is the `[10]` necessary in this loop here? Even if I use index (`while(a[i]!='\0')`) instead of pointers, I have to do the same to get the correct output.

This is what I have in mind the array looks:[image]
So I think a[5] will automatically become `\0` and loop will end.

Comment: You seem to be expecting a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) at the end of the array. That doesn't happen automatically. If you want a sentinel value at the end of the array, you need to put one there, e.g. `..., "GRIMMJOW", ""};`

Comment: I think your main issue you do not fully understand pointers. What is char\*? What is char \*\*,   char (\*)[10]  ? How increment works in char* and char \*\*, and on (\*)[10] and what do you get when de-referencing them.  If you understand those clearly, you will understand your code errors.

Comment: In the first case it does not run 31 times which is equal to the number of characters in array a, the behaviour is undefined. Likewise in the second case. Neither code *works* for any proper definition of "working".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your program is wrong.

`ptr` is a pointer to an array (of 10 char). So `*ptr` is an array of 10 chars. So it doesn't make sense to compare `*ptr`with `\0` as `*ptr` wont be null.

When you do the compare `*ptr` will first point to "AIZEN", after the increment it will point to "GINJO" and so on. For each increment of `ptr`, `*ptr` will simply be incremented by 10. After 5 increments you access outside the array when you do `printf("%s\n",*ptr);`. That's undefined behavior and anything may happen.

Trying this

```
while(*ptr != '\0'){
    printf("%s\n",*ptr);
    printf("%p\n",(void*)ptr);
    printf("%p\n",(void*)*ptr);
    ptr++;
}
```

may result in output like this

```
AIZEN
0x7ffd162228c0
0x7ffd162228c0
GINJO
0x7ffd162228ca
0x7ffd162228ca
ISHIDA
0x7ffd162228d4
0x7ffd162228d4
PERNIDA
0x7ffd162228de
0x7ffd162228de
GRIMMJOW
0x7ffd162228e8
0x7ffd162228e8

0x7ffd162228f2
0x7ffd162228f2

0x7ffd162228fc
0x7ffd162228fc

0x7ffd16222906
0x7ffd16222906
P@
0x7ffd16222910
0x7ffd16222910
nɜ
0x7ffd1622291a
0x7ffd1622291a
```

Here you see how the pointers increment and that the print statement generates all kind of strange things (due to undefined behavior but it could also have crashed the program).

You can change your program like:

```
int main(void) {
    char a[][10]={"AIZEN","GINJO","ISHIDA","PERNIDA","GRIMMJOW", ""};  // Notice
                                                                       // the empty string
                                                                       // to stop
                                                                       // the loop
    char (*ptr)[10]=a;
    while(**ptr !='\0'){       // Notice **
        printf("%s\n",*ptr);
        printf("%p\n",(void*)ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That is: 1) add an empty string to the array and 2) dereference the pointer to check for a NUL (i.e. the string termination)

Also notice that in your second example `(*ptr)[10]!='\0'` makes no sense either. You access the 11'th element in the array (aka string) but the array is only 10 elements.

Comment: Unfortunately you can compare an array with a pointer (the array decays to the pointer to first element) and `'\0'` is also a valid way to express the null pointer constant. That's why the code compiles...

Comment: array of 10 `char`, without star.

Comment: The `**ptr` is checking the first character of each string, and then the end string `""` comes up and thus `**ptr` finally becomes equal to `\0`, ending the loop. Did I understand that right?

Comment: @Adnan Exactly - that's correct. It checks the first character of each string and the empty string consists of one character which is `\0`

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems:

1. The test `while (*ptr != '\0') {...}` is not doing what you think is doing. The reason the code compiles is that unfortunately the character constant `'\0'` can also be considered the null pointer constant(*). What you meant was probably comparing the character with `while (**ptr != '\0') {...}`.
2. The array `char a[][10]={...}` will only have as many elements as you declare. If you want to terminate it you need to add an extra `""` element at the end. This way the extra empty element will be detected by the loop condition.

Accessing outside of the array as your code is doing is undefined behavior and anything can happen (including looping 31 times).

(*) The wording used by the standard is "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant". Caracters in C are integers and therefore `'\0'` is an integer constant expression with value 0. Good compilers should still warn about this case as it's a common mistake (e.g. `gcc -Wall` will warn 
 explicitly about a possibly missing dereference).

Comment: So if I want to use `NULL` instead of `'\0'`, then what should I use? Directly using NULL will be comparing pointer to integer.

Comment: @Adnan You can't use NULL in the compare. Your array is an array of array of **char**. You can't store a NULL the aarray. And further, your `*ptr` will not become NULL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

See this,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[][10]={"AIZEN","GINJO","ISHIDA","PERNIDA","GRIMMJOW"};
    char (*ptr)[10]=a;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++,ptr++)
        printf("%s\n",ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

In your code

```
   while(*ptr!='\0');
```

ptr did not come to null

or change

```
char a[][10]={"AIZEN","GINJO","ISHIDA","PERNIDA","GRIMMJOW",""}; //string literels are NULL terminated by the compiler

while(**ptr!='\0');
```

Note:

```
 *ptr refer to initial address of string

 **ptr refer to address of character in the string
```